# KitKat ANR when accessing empty contact photo

Tags: java, android, contactscontract

For my app I read the contact's photo from the ContactsContract API which worked fine up until Android KitKat. I can't find anything specific about changes to the ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream() method in the 4.4 change log but I can only replicate this on KitKat and when there is no photo present for that contact.

I read from the contacts using this:

```
public static Bitmap getContactPhoto(final Uri lookupUri, final Context context, boolean preferHighRes) 
        throws IOException, OutOfMemoryError, NullPointerException{
    InputStream photo_stream = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(context.getContentResolver(), 
            lookupUri, preferHighRes);
    BufferedInputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(photo_stream);
    Bitmap contactImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
    input.close();
    return contactImg;
}
```

This method is called like so:

```
private class retrieveContactPhoto extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> {

    Uri contactUri;
    ImageView imageView;

    public retrieveContactPhoto(Uri contactUri, ImageView iView){
        this.contactUri = contactUri;
        this.imageView = iView;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.friend_image_default);
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Bitmap image;
        try {
            image = ContactLookup.getContactPhoto(contactUri, mContext, true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            image = null;
        }
        return image;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap image) {
        if(image!=null){
            imageView.setImageBitmap(image);
        }
    }
}
```

This will work for a few seconds but after that I will get plenty of grief in the LogCat (Usually over half million lines of errors!?)

```
11-28 11:05:03.067: W/System.err(9507): java.io.IOException: BufferedInputStream is closed
11-28 11:05:03.077: W/System.err(9507):     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.streamClosed(BufferedInputStream.java:118)
11-28 11:05:03.087: W/System.err(9507):     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:279)
11-28 11:05:03.097: W/System.err(9507):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
11-28 11:05:03.097: W/System.err(9507):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:719)
11-28 11:05:03.097: W/System.err(9507):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:791)
11-28 11:05:03.097: W/System.err(9507):     at com.repay.android.addDebt.ContactLookup.getContactPhoto(ContactLookup.java:31)
11-28 11:05:03.097: W/System.err(9507):     at com.repay.android.StartFragmentAdapter$retrieveContactPhoto.doInBackground(StartFragmentAdapter.java:110)
11-28 11:05:03.097: W/System.err(9507):     at com.repay.android.StartFragmentAdapter$retrieveContactPhoto.doInBackground(StartFragmentAdapter.java:1)
11-28 11:05:03.097: W/System.err(9507):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
11-28 11:05:03.107: W/System.err(9507):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
11-28 11:05:03.107: W/System.err(9507):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
11-28 11:05:03.107: W/System.err(9507):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
11-28 11:05:03.117: W/System.err(9507):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
11-28 11:05:03.117: W/System.err(9507):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
11-28 11:05:03.117: W/System.err(9507):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
```

I'm not sure why it now says about the stream being closed since this doesn't happen on any other version of Android. Also, this error will still appear if it's not in a worker thread.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Im having a similar issue

Comment: Having a similar issue as well. ANR accesing a contact photo in 4.4

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to do a small change in your code? I had a similar problem - my app just stayed in a infinite loop.

Try this:

```
InputStream photo_stream = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream((ContentResolver) getContentResolver().query(ContactData, null, null, null, null),lookupUri, preferHighRes);
```

This worked for me.